# Do archery style and swift quiver apply to hand crossbows?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger

Let's say that a ranger had archery fighting style and used up a spell slot for *swift quiver*, and for some unknown reason, decided to use a hand crossbow. Do those two things apply for hand crossbows?

Answer (score 25):

### Yes and No.

> **Archery** - You gain a +2 bonus to attack rolls you make with
>   ranged weapons.

Archery works with hand-crossbows, as they are ranged weapons.

> **Swift Quiver** - On each of your turns until the spell ends, you can use a bonus action to make two attacks with a weapon that uses ammunition from the quiver.

This doesn't exclude a hand crossbow from using it. However, crossbows are known for their *Loading* property.

> **Loading** - Because of the time required to load this weapon, you can fire only one piece of ammunition from it when you use an action, Bonus Action, or reaction to fire it, regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make.

So you can only make one attack with it. In other words, you can fire the crossbow with your Action, and fire it again (but only once!) with your bonus action.

However! There is hope if you take the *Crossbow Expert* feat.

> **Crossbow Expert** - You ignore the loading quality of crossbows with which you are proficient.

This would allow you to efficiently use the *Swift Quiver* effect.

Answer (score 4):

### Archery? Yes.

> ...to attack rolls you make **with ranged weapons**. (PHB p.91, emphasis mine)

A hand crossbow is a ranged weapon (PHB p.149: it's in the ranged section of the table), so it qualifies for "archery."

### *Swift quiver*? Yes.

> ...a weapon that uses ammunition. (PHB p.279)

A hand crossbow uses ammunition (PHB p.149 again), so it qualifies for *swift quiver*.

### But what about Loading? DM's ruling.

The hand crossbow also has the property "loading":

> Because of the time required to load this weapon, you can fire only one piece of ammunition from it when you use an action, bonus action, or reaction to fire it, regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make.

So you've got a spell that makes your ammo so quick that you can make more attacks, but a weapon property that rate-limits ammo going into it. Which trumps which? I don't think the rules are clear, so you're going to have to talk to your GM and get their ruling. I can see reasonable interpretations either way:

- **Still only one firing:** the spell makes the quiver and ammo swifter, not the weapon itself. Even though ammo's springing into your hand, there's a bottleneck at the crossbow's throat.
- **Fire away:** the swiftness of the ammo applies all the way to its loading; the spell says you *can* make the two attacks, so loading bows to that (for one minute).